# Слово "кромешный"

Tags: этимология

Читала где-то, что слово "кромешный" проиходит от слова "кромка". Но "крошемный" употребляется в значении "беспросветный", "абсолютный" ("кромешная тьма", "ад кромешный"). Почему так? И, кстати, родственное ли этим словам слово "закром"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, при чем тут собственно кромка, по Фасмеру это "кромешный" родственно "кроме" (чего-то, кого-то), в историческом значении - внешний, потусторонний. Думаю, такое объяснение самодостаточно. ад кромешный или тьма кромешная - то, что находится за пределами понимаемого мира.
Иногда, правда, пытаются свести значение "кромешный" в этих выражениях напрямую к "кроме", т.е. "исключительный", "ничего кроме тьмы", но это противоречит исторической семантике слова "кромешный".

Кромка, видимо, из этого же ряда, но это никак не "предок" кромешного, а какой-то дальнмй родственник.

кстати, вот [обсуждение](http://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/794742.html), где много интересных фактов

Answer (score 0):

Кромкой встарь называли линию горизонта,а за ней считалось начинается неизведанное- тьма.Скорей всего отсюда и кромешный.